# Numpy Indexing of 2 Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider two numpy arrays

```
a = np.array(['john', 'bill', 'greg', 'bill', 'bill', 'greg', 'bill'])
b = np.array(['john', 'bill', 'greg'])
```

How would I be able to produce a third array

```
c = np.array([0,1,2,1,1,2,1])
```

The same length as `a` representing the index of each entry of `a` in the array `b`?

I can see a way by looping over the elements of `b` as `b[i]` and checking `np.where(a == b[i])` but was wondering if numpy could accomplish this in a quicker/better/less lines of code way.

Comment: The "c" you want is 1 + the index, or actually the index?

Comment: Ah yes, indexing mistake there, I will edit the question. It should be the actual index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(['john', 'bill', 'greg', 'bill', 'bill', 'greg', 'bill'])
b = np.array(['john', 'bill', 'greg'])

my_dict = dict(zip(b, range(len(b))))

result = np.vectorize(my_dict.get)(a)
```

Result:

```
>>> result
array([0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1])
```

Comment: result = np.vectorize(my_dict.get)(a,-1)  if the elements in a might not be in b

Comment: vectorize is just a convenience function with a Python for loop under the hood. You are saving developer time, but not CPU time.

Answer (score 5):

Sorting is a good option for vectorization with numpy:

```
>>> s = np.argsort(b)
>>> s[np.searchsorted(b, a, sorter=s)]
array([0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1], dtype=int64)
```

If your array `a` has `m` elements and `b` has `n`, the sorting is going to be O(n log n), and the searching O(m log n), which is not bad. Dictionary based solutions should be amortized linear, but if the arrays are not huge the Python looping may make them slower than this. And broadcasting based solutions have quadratic complexity, they will only be faster for very small arrays.

---

Some timings with your sample:

```
In [3]: %%timeit
   ...: s = np.argsort(b)
   ...: np.take(s, np.searchsorted(b, a, sorter=s))
   ...: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.16 µs per loop

In [5]: %%timeit
   ...: my_dict = dict(zip(b, range(len(b))))
   ...: np.vectorize(my_dict.get)(a)
   ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.9 µs per loop

In [7]: %timeit (np.arange(b.size)*(a==b[:,newaxis]).T).sum(axis=-1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.5 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a dictionary for translating each string to number and then use [`numpy.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) for creating the output array

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(['john', 'bill', 'greg', 'bill', 'bill', 'greg', 'bill'])
>>> b = np.array(['john', 'bill', 'greg'])
>>> d = {k:v for v, k in enumerate(b)}
>>> c = np.vectorize(d.get)(a)
>>> c
 array([0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1])
```

This is more efficient than looping and doing `np.where(a == b[i])` because you only visit one element of the array once.

Answer (score 3):

Fully numpy solution:

```
(arange(b.size)*(a==b[:,newaxis]).T).sum(axis=-1)
```

Comment: Interesting solution! Seems to be the fastest one, too. Unfortunately not easy to read...

Comment: This is the right solution. If you had made it PEP8 and not considered  * imported from numpy, it would have been perfect :)

Comment: Actually, an `np.where(a[:, np.newaxis] == b)[1]` would have done it, too.

Comment: @eickenberg +1. I wanted to avoid `where`, because I was expecting it to be slower. It turns out that: for small arrays `where` is actually faster; for large arrays it is a bit slower.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is possible by:

```
arr, bSorted, ind =  np.unique(a, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)
c = bSorted[ind]
```

If you wanted to get the unique elements out of `a` and do not care about the order in `b`, i.e. `b` and therefore `c` will look differently, then it can be simplified to

```
b, c = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the array `b` contains unique elements, equality with an element of `a` can only ever be  with one single element of `b`. If all elements of `a` are definitely in `b`, then

```
import numpy as np
indices = np.where(a[:, np.newaxis] == b)[1]
```

will do the trick. If you are not sure whether all elements of `a` are in `b`, then

```
in_b, indices = np.where(a[:, np.newaxis] == b)
```

will collect all elements of `a` which are contained in `b` in `in_b`